# IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type A to required type : no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Tags: java, spring

IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type A to required type : no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Getting this exception while deploying my spring application. Implementation class is extending another class along with implementing interface, which i am suspecting causing this issue.

I tried some of the solutions mentioned in other posts as well. 
Have verified that Interface is mapped to bean
and also tried with Inject and Qualifier annotation as well. But none of these solve the problem.

Comment: Could you please share some code?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and after that comeback to your question and improve it.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when:

1. you are using interface-based AOP (ie: only JDK proxies, no CGLIB or whatever)
2. your injection point references a class and not an interface

Example:

```
public class MyConcreteClass extends MyAbstractClass implements MyInterface {
// ... my class implementation

}

...

public class MyClient {
    ...
    // injection point: note that the parameter is MyAbstractClass and
    // not MyInterface
    public void setMyClass(MyAbstractClass injectedInstance) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

As JDK only proxies interfaces and not classes, you get this error. Changing that to `setMyClass(MyInterface injectedInstance)` should solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am using spring getters/setters way of bean injection and as i mentioned in first post, I am ensuring interface is mapped to injected instance.                                                                                             Another thing i noticed here is, my extended class in implementing another interface. Will this be an issue? Eg : In above code, MyAbstractClass is implementing another interface.

Comment: The error is not what your class implements, but the setter signature. So `setMyClass(MyAbstractClass)` fails with JDK proxies, but `setMyClass(MyInterface)`  succeeds.
It also might be some other problem urelated to this.